# How long for kids to play after spraying

Tags: weed-control, safety

How soon can kids play on lawn if roundup was sprayed? I just sprayed roundup on the perimeter of my lawn, my 4 year old wants to go play in the yard, how long until it's safe also how long will it be safe for the weed killer to get wet if it rains?

Comment: Read the label. Not sure why you'd spray a broad-spectrum herbicide on your lawn; or is this something that's RoundUp branded but **not** the Non-Hodgkins Lymphoma causing glyphosate that the brand was built on? Unspecified, glyphosate is assumed when you just say RoundUp.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manufacturer, Roundup is safe for children and animals as soon as it has fully dried on. The same goes for washing off. If you have to use biocides, always keep and read the label, which legally has to have this sort of information on it.